# DRF: how to validate arguments passed to serializer.save()?

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

How can I validate an additional arguments passed like this:

```
class MyViewSet(MultiSerializerViewSet):
    # some stuff

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(creator=self.request.user)
```

How can I validate a `creator` in the serializer?

Comment: you can write checks at model definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not validate fields passed as arguments to **serializer.save()** method, they will only be available in **create** method of the serializer, and I suggest not to run validations there. What I do in these kind of situations is, I override the **create** method of the viewset, and add extra parameters to the data I pass to the serializer.

```
class MyViewSet(MultiSerializerViewSet):
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        request_data = request.data
        request_data['creator'] = self.user.id

        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request_data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

With this setup, you also need to add **creator** as a serializer field. With this, the field will be alailable in validtion flow.

Answer (score 0):

Django reset framework has **is_valid()** method validate serializer

for e.g.

```
serializer = YourSerializer(data={'sample1': 'foobar', 'sample2': 'baz'})
serializer.is_valid()
# False
serializer.errors
# {'sample1': ['Some error.'], 'sample2': ['Some error.']}
```

refer [this](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#validation)

Comment: no, I mean I want to validate if creator has created my_model related model_2 => he can create instance, else => raise Validation error. creator by his own is valid field name.